# Create AutoMapper modules like Ninject modules?

Tags: automapper

It is possible to create automapper like modules (such thoses of ninject) so i can define my mappings from an external library here and include them in a bootstrap class ?

Answer (score 0):

That is exactly what [Bootstrapper](http://bootstrapper.codeplex.com/) does. All you have to do is implement IMapCreator and Bootstrapper will find and execute your mapping code at startup time.